# Styling two buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to **WPF** and  please help me out to achieve my goal for this project.
The corner of stream button from right side and chart button from left side should not be cornered. I want to achieve this:

[image]

But currently they are looking like this shown below. Current styling for buttons:

[image]

TextAnswersSkin.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="LoginSkin.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MainSkin.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style x:Key="ShadowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="listBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ToggleBtnStyle_forname" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <!--<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="checkedVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="UnCheckedVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF0095C6"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF006687"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF002A37"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF0AA3D5" Fill="#FF4CBFE4"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{x:Null}" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="2">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4EC0E4" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF0DA4D6"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="UnCheckedVisual" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Show Wordcloud" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="checkedVisual" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,0">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hide Wordcloud" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ToggleBtnStyle_chart" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>


        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <!--<Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF0095C6"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>-->
                                <!--<Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF01556E"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF006A89"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF026A89"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>-->
                                <Storyboard>


                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF026A89"/>


                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!--<BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">

                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="10:00:00" Value="False" />



                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->

                                </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>


                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <!--<Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF006687"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>-->
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <!--<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF006687"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>-->
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF0AA3D5" Fill="#FF4CBFE4"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{x:Null}" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="2">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4EC0E4" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF0DA4D6"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>



                    <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ToggleBtnStyle_stream" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">


        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <!--<Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1" >
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF0095C6"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>-->
                                <Storyboard>

                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">

                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF026A89"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">

                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>                                  
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF0AA3D5" Fill="#FF4CBFE4"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{x:Null}" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="2">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4EC0E4" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF0DA4D6"/>

                            </LinearGradientBrush>

                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>


                    <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                </Grid>


            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>



                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>


            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

TextAnswers.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResponseSystem.Controls.TextAnswers"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ResponseSystem.ViewModel"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ResponseSystem.Controls"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Visibility="{Binding TextAnswersVisibility}"
         x:Name="tac"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" ClipToBounds="True" >

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Q-Launcher;component/Skins/MainSkin.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Q-Launcher;component/Skins/LoginSkin.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Q-Launcher;component/Skins/TextAnswersSkin.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="Main" />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Height>1*</RowDefinition.Height>
        </RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ToggleButton x:Name="btnShowStream"  Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnStyle_stream}" 
                         Margin="10,0,-2,0" Height="20"
                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Command="{Binding ShowStreamCommand}" 



                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=TextAnswersStreamVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding Path=TextAnswersChartVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Foreground="White"
                         d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Padding="0,0,2,0">
            <TextBlock Text=" Stream " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ToggleButton>

            <ToggleButton x:Name="btnShowChart" Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnStyle_stream}" 
                         Height="20" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,0"
                          Padding="2,0,0,0"

                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Command="{Binding ShowChartCommand}" 
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=TextAnswersChartVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding Path=TextAnswersStreamVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisiblityToBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Foreground="White"
                         d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
                <TextBlock Text=" Chart " VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            </ToggleButton>
            <!--<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=btnShowStream, Path=IsChecked}"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=btnShowChart, Path=IsChecked}"></Label>-->
            <!--IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowChart, Converter={StaticResource BoolToNullableBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"--> 
        </StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnStyle_forname}" x:Name="btnShowWordcloud" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                      Command="{Binding ShowWordcloudCommand}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowWordcloud, Converter={StaticResource BoolToNullableBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      Margin="0,0,10,0" Height="20" Width="105" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"  Foreground="White">
            <!--Visibility="{Binding AnonymousVisibility}"-->
            <TextBlock Text="Show Wordcloud" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ToggleButton>
       </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <controls:TextAnswersStream x:Name="AnswersStream" Visibility="{Binding Path=TextAnswersStreamVisibility}">
                 <controls:TextAnswersStream.ClipToBounds>True</controls:TextAnswersStream.ClipToBounds>
                </controls:TextAnswersStream>
          </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
               <controls:TextAnswersChart  x:Name="AnswersChart" Visibility="{Binding Path=TextAnswersChartVisibility}">
               <controls:TextAnswersChart.ClipToBounds>True</controls:TextAnswersChart.ClipToBounds>
               </controls:TextAnswersChart>
            </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What did you tried? Can you provides some code? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please share button style for study

Comment: @KingKing `CornerRadius` allows individual values for `TopLeft`, `TopRight` etc.

Comment: @grek40 my bad, it's a long time I've not worked with WPF, forgot ***a lot of*** things I had learnt before.

Comment: Sorry everyone and I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a control template for your button.

After you can define a style for border for a proper settings of parameters.

An example to create these buttons :

[Image of buttons created by the code in example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDAkl.png)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">

    <Button Content="Stream" Width="75">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="8,0,0,8" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

    <Button Content="Chart" Width="75" Margin="-1,0,0,0">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="0,8,8,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: how should I implement in TextAnswersSkin.Xaml as I have a custom style for both buttons.

Comment: As I don't want to create two different styles for these buttons

Comment: You can create only one style to set common values : Brush, Thickness, Color... And after you set the non common properties in each button (ex CornerRadius)